# How to get access to procedure parameter DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have next procedure for adding partitions into table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GBC_CR20877_CDWH.ADD_NEW_PARTITIONS (
    IN TBL_NAME VARCHAR(32)
    ,IN DATE_FROM DATE
    ,IN DATE_TO DATE
    ,IN TBL_SPC_NM VARCHAR(32)
    ,IN SRC_STM VARCHAR(8)
    ,IN NCI_SCHEME VARCHAR(32)
    ) LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE stmt2 VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE ALTER_DDL_SQL VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE S1 STATEMENT;

    DECLARE ALTER_PARTITIONS CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || TBL_NAME || ' ADD PARTITION PART' || MSR_PRD_ID || '_' || SRC_STM || ' STARTING FROM (' || MSR_PRD_ID || ', ' || SRC_STM || ') ENDING AT (' || MSR_PRD_ID || ', ' || SRC_STM || ') IN ' || TBL_SPC_NM || ' INDEX IN ' || TBL_SPC_NM || ' LONG IN ' || TBL_SPC_NM || ';'
    FROM NCI_SCHEME
    WHERE EFF_DT BETWEEN DATE_FROM
            AND DATE_TO
    ORDER BY MSR_PRD_ID;
END
```

I try to make a cursor with many DDL commands ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION. Later I would like to execute these commands in cycle looping through the cursor.

I have problem with parameter NCI_SCHEME. I want to use it as source table in select query, but using like that I get an error:

> Run: GBC_CR20877_CDWH.ADD_NEW_PARTITIONS(VARCHAR(32), DATE, DATE,
>   VARCHAR(32), VARCHAR(8), VARCHAR(32))
>
> {call GBC_CR20877_CDWH.ADD_NEW_PARTITIONS(?,?,?,?,?,?)}
>
> An error occurred during implicit system action type "3". Information
>   returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and
>   message tokens "MY_USERNAME.NCI_SCHEME".. SQLCODE=-727,
>   SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=3.66.46
>
> Run of routine failed.
>
> - Roll back completed successfully.

However, if I hardcode table_name without parameter it works fine! I don't understand why other parameters in select query work, but NCI_SCHEME doesn't. Any help please!)

Comment: If you want the table-name to be an input-parameter, then you must use dynamic-SQL, instead of the static-SQL that is in your cursor. Do more research on learning how to create the SQL dynamically, then use either EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement (or make the SQL, then PREPARE and EXECUTE it ). IBM also gives samples in the Knowledge Center and in the server SAMPLES directory.

Comment: thx, ur comment direct me to solution!